# Minimod Pretty Print - How to customize line breaks?

Tags: c#, pretty-print

I'm using Minimod.PrettyPrint. For multidimensional lists and arrays, the PrettyPrint() function inserts line breaks between elements automatically if the elements are over a certain length.

**My question is - How do I control when the line breaks happen between array elements?** Specifically, I'd like all array elements to have a line break between them. For example, I would like the function

```
// myArray is of type int[][] 
myArray.PrettyPrint(/*insert customization here to make the line break*/);
```

to output

```
[
  [<elements of myArray[0]>],
  [<elements of myArray[1]>],
  [<elements of myArray[2]>]
]
```

By default, `PrettyPrint()` will print this as

```
 [[<elements of myArray[0]>],[<elements of myArray[1]>],[<elements of myArray[2]>]]
```

if the length the string written by `PrettyPrint()` is below a certain length.

There is an overload of `PrettyPrint()` that takes an object to customize the output, but I can't find examples of how to use it.

Edit: I've tried

```
PrettyPrintMinimod.Settings settings = new PrettyPrintMinimod.Settings();
settings.PreferMultiline(true);
myArray.PrettyPrint(settings);
```

and it doesn't seem to do anything. If I pass `settings.PreferMultiline(false)` to an array with many elements, I still get line breaks, and if I pass `settings.PreferMultiline(true)` I don't get line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works OK for me:

```
var test = new int[][] { new int[] {1,2,3}, new int[] {4,5,6} };

var settings = new PrettyPrintMinimod.Settings();
settings.PreferMultiline(true);
Debug.WriteLine(test.PrettyPrint(settings));
```

It produces output like this:

```
[
  [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  [
    4,
    5,
    6
  ]
]
```

If that's not really what you're after, there's always the nuclear option - write your own formatter:

```
settings.RegisterFormatterFor(typeof(int[][]), o => {
    var array2d = (int[][])o;
    return "[\r\n" + string.Join(",\r\n", 
        array2d.Select(array1d => "\t[" + string.Join(", ", 
            array1d.Select(s => s.ToString())) + "]")) + "\r\n]";
});

Debug.WriteLine(test.PrettyPrint(settings));
```

Which produces output like this:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]
```